# Pepper plants too close

Tags: plant-health, peppers, bell-peppers, jalapenos

I have 2 pepper plants that are right in top of each other, can I just cut the weaker one one out? And it Will be ok?

Answer (score 1):

A picture would be nice and a description of the length and size as well. If they are smaller size and you can replant them then do so. If they are big it might be harder due to the roots and stress it can cause. But, you can examine and prune or cut out the weaker and more damaged one. Try next time to give it a few centimeters of distance to avoid issues like this.